# Events in NodeJS, event is being emitted, within setInterval, but not without setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events, eventemitter

I am very new to JavaScript and NodeJS, I was just trying to understand the emitter pattern in NodeJS. When I try to emit a tick event every second, using the `setInterval` function, the program seems to be working fine:-

```
        var util = require('util'),
        EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

        var Ticker = function() {
          var self = this;
          setInterval(function() {
            self.emit('tick');
          }, 1000);
        };

        util.inherits(Ticker, EventEmitter)

        var ticker = new Ticker();
        ticker.on('tick', function() {
          console.log('TICK');
        });
```

But, when I try to emit an event without using the `setInterval` method, my event is not being called:-

```
        var util = require('util'),
            EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

        var Ticker = function() {
          var self = this;
          self.emit('tick');
        };

        util.inherits(Ticker, EventEmitter)

        var ticker = new Ticker();
        ticker.on('tick', function() {
          console.log('TICK');
        });
```

Please help, I don't understand, where I am wrong...
As far as my understanding, when `self.emit` is called, `ticker.on` is not registered, and hence the event is missed. If this is the case, how do I emit an event when an object is created?

Comment: Tip: when inheriting you should call the parent constructor in your constructor in case it needs to perform initialization of its own. In this particular case that would mean adding `EventEmitter.call(this);` inside your constructor function (`Ticker()`).

Comment: Hi, I tried using your tip, in the constructor, it showed an error saying ticker.on is not a function

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a (mostly*) synchronous language, unless otherwise specified, code runs from top to bottom, and only asynchronous events are queued for later.

Without the setInterval queuing the `emit()` for later, you have something like this:

```
create Ticker
Ticker.emit()
Ticker.on(...)
```

So basically, the `.emit()` happens synchronously, and before the first call to `.on()`.

---

*Mostly because with ES2015 we have Promises, which are a language-level construct for describing something asynchronous, that's not important, however, for the problem you're observing.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your response, but what am I supposed to do, if I have to emit an event, when my object is created?

Comment: Use `setTimeout(() => this.emit(), 0)` or something similar to make sure it's emitted asynchronously.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

> how do I emit an event when an object is created

You already know the answer. Just listen to that event before triggering it. There is no other solutions. Asynchronously firing `emit` is just a messier one. And also, I don't recommend writing ES5 on nodejs.

```
let Event = require('event');
class Ticker extends Event{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.on('tick', () => {
          console.log('TICK');
        });
        this.emit('tick');
    }
}
new Ticker();

// or better
class Ticker extends Event{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
}
var ticker = new Ticker();
ticker.on('tick', () => {
  console.log('TICK');
});
ticker.emit('tick');
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that you need someone to emit the event.
It can be a function, setInterval, setTimeout etc..

The usage of event emitter is only to bind all those functions,
to be called when a given event is emitted by someone..

Hence you will always need someone to emit events.